# Trigger failure AFTER UPDATE on MariaDB

Tags: sql, triggers, mariadb

I am trying to automate some tasks within a DB rather than in the app. We have a small MariaDB for tickets to be sold. When a ticket is sold, its status needs to be set to NOT_VALID until payment is made. After payment is made, the ticket needs to be set to VALID. The invoice itself is in a table 'som_accounting' and with a reference table (som_accountingtickets - because of lazy design decisions) it points to the tickets. Now I am trying to automate that the flag in the ticket table is set to VALID when the PAYMENTSTATUS column in the accounting table changes from OPEN (1) to PAYED (3).

When I use this on the console (dbeaver or terminal) it works fine:

```
UPDATE som_ticket SET ID_ticketstatus = 4, activation_date = CURRENT_DATE()
WHERE ticketID IN
(SELECT act.ID_ticket FROM som_accountingticket act
   INNER JOIN (SELECT * FROM som_accounting) AS ac
       ON ac.accountingID = act.ID_accounting
   INNER JOIN (SELECT * FROM som_ticket) AS t2
       ON t2.ticketID = act.ID_ticket AND t2.ID_ticketstatus = '1'
   WHERE act.ID_accounting = '565');
```

Now I put this into a trigger an I got an error:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`<user>`@`%` TRIGGER `somt_au_accounting`
      AFTER UPDATE
      ON `som_accounting`
      
      FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
            
            IF NEW.ID_paymentstatus = 3 AND OLD.ID_paymentstatus = 1 THEN
                UPDATE som_ticket SET ID_ticketstatus = '4', 
                                            activation_date = CURRENT_DATE()
                    WHERE ticketID IN 
                              (SELECT act.ID_ticket FROM som_accountingticket act
                     INNER JOIN (SELECT * FROM som_accounting) AS ac
                                         ON ac.accountingID = act.ID_accounting
                                   INNER JOIN (SELECT * FROM som_ticket) AS t2
                                         ON t2.ticketID = act.ID_ticket
                                   AND t2.ID_ticketstatus = '1'
                                   WHERE act.ID_accounting = OLD.accountingID);
            END IF;
      END
```

Database reports this:

```
Error synchronizing data with database

Reason:
SQL-Fehler [08]: (conn:3) Could not read resultset: unexpected end of stream, read 0 bytes from 4
Query is: UPDATE d0294220.som_accounting
    SET ID_paymentstatus=?
    WHERE accountingID=?, parameters [3,568]
```

Why did it run well in the console but not in the trigger?

MariaDB 10.5.8

Comment: The error looks like it's from some other query? ... No part of the trigger's query has `SET ID_paymentstatus`.

Comment: The set of the new ID_paymanetstatus is done in the app. If an invoice gets paid the user change this value in the app from 1 (not payed yet) to 3 (payed) and the trigger listens to exact this change and should do the rest.

Comment: Then the only other matter that I can see is that query moved into the trigger, makes a reference to the same table that fires the trigger (at the inner join), which is not allowed. `Cannot make changes to a table that is already in use (reading or writing) by the statement invoking the stored function.` That information from [MariaDB trigger limits](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/trigger-limitations/), in the second bullet item details.

Comment: I splited the job now. The trigger only check if something is to do: if paymentstatus changed from 1 to 3 then call a stored procedure and pass the accountingID. The procedure searches all the tickets to change and set them to VALID.